# How to implement HTTPS in AWS Elastic Bean Stalk using PHP/Apache

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Have seen many threads on this topic which all seems active few years back. Bit confused on how this can be done.

Following is the environment config:
64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.1 running PHP 5.6
I'm assuming the installation comes default with Apache.

I gather it can be done code level and also Webserver level. I got an impression that web server level approach would be generic and probably the best approach. Is there a step by step help to install a digital certificate and redirect http to https in AWS Elastic Bean Stalk?

Thanks so much as it would incredibly help me to secure the website.

Comment: You can either install the SSL certificate in Apache or on the Elastic Load balancer. So that's the web server or load balancer, not "code level" whatever that means. You could also use the new AWS ACM service if you are using the US-EAST region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon has introduced Certificate Manager timely and it has provided an easy way to implement HTTPS